# Qt Как правильно составить SQL запрос

Tags: c++, sql, qt

Qt. Делаю регистрацию. На данный момент делаю проверку зарегистрирован ли уже такой email, если нет, регистрировать, если да, выводить QMessageBox

```
QSqlQuery qry;
        //Checking is email has already registered
        qry.prepare("SELECT `email` FROM `users` AS `:email` WHERE `email` = `:email`");
        qry.bindValue(":email", emailforcheck);
        
        bool isntreg = true;
        if(qry.exec())
        {
            QMessageBox::information(this, "s", emailforcheck); // вывод переменной для проверки что записалось
            if(emailforcheck == email)
            {
                QMessageBox::warning(this, "Реєстрація", "Акаунт з таким email вже зареєстрований!");
                isntreg = false;
            }
        }
```

Вот кусок кода с проверкой зарегистрирован ли email, но QMessageBox с переменной emailforcheck даже не выводит, не пишет, что email зарегистрирован (в БД зарегистрирован). Прошу помощи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. QSqlQuery используете неправильно - SqlQuery::exec() только выполняет запрос. Чтобы получить результат, необходимо его запросить используя [SqlQuery::next()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqlquery.html#next)
   (или last(), или first())
2. Сам SQL запрос можно сделать проще, к тому же есть подозрение что ваше выполняется с ошибкой
3. переменная email нигде не объявлена и нигде не присвоена, а уж что значит if(emailforcheck == email) и вовсе загадка

Подведя итог. Проверить есть ли в таблице запись с заданным email можно так

```
QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = :email"); // Можно просто запросить количество записей с заданным email
qry.bindValue(":email", emailforcheck);
if(!qry.exec()){ // Контролируйте выполнение запроса и выводите ошибки если они возникают  
   QMessageBox::information(this, "sql error", qry.lastError().text());
   return;
};
bool isntreg = true;
qry.next(); // Запрос выполнился, но надо запросить результат
if(qry.value(0).toInt()>0){
    QMessageBox::warning(this, "Реєстрація", "Акаунт з таким email вже зареєстрований!");
    isntreg = false;
}
```

Comment: Переменные объявлены выше в коде, emailforcheck пустой т.к в него записываем данные из запроса, а email - емейл из lineedit